# Why is SimpleImputer returning categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, imputation

I'm imputing values into a dataframe using `fillna` for the numerical columns and `SimpleImputer` for the categorical columns. The problem is that when I ran the following code, I noticed that all of my features are categorical.

```py
X = X.fillna(X.mean())
X_test = X_test.fillna(X_test.mean())

object_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")
X_temp = pd.DataFrame(object_imputer.fit_transform(X))
X_temp_test = pd.DataFrame(object_imputer.fit_transform(X_test))
X_temp.columns = X.columns
X_temp_test.columns = X_test.columns
X, X_test = X_temp, X_temp_test
```

The `fillna` works fine, but it's the `SimpleImputer` that is causing me problems.

Can you please tell me what the problem is and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd love to help, but it's difficult without a minimal reproducible example. Can you please provide a representative subset of your data so we can run the code and know how to help? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The whole dataset is here: https://www.kaggle.com/hossamhibrahem/loan-prediction-analytics-vidhya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I say anything else, note that you are fitting your imputer on `X` and then on `X_test`. You should never do this. Instead, you should always fit your imputer on the training data and then use that instance to transform both datasets (training and testing data).

Having said that, your problem is that you are fitting and transforming all columns. As a consequence, the imputer is transforming all columns to type `object`.

I believe this will solve your problem:

```py
# Impute NaNs of numeric columns
X = X.fillna(X.mean())
X_test = X_test.fillna(X_test.mean())

# Subset of categorical columns
cat = ['Loan_ID','Gender','Married','Dependents','Education','Self_Employed',
       'Credit_History','Loan_Status']
# Fit Imputer on traing data and ONLY on categorical columns
object_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent').fit(X[cat])
# Transform ONLY categorical columns
X[cat] = object_imputer.transform(X[cat])
X_test[cat] = object_imputer.transform(X_test[cat])
```

As you can see, all columns have the correct data type now.

```py
X.dtypes
Loan_ID               object
Gender                object
Married               object
Dependents            object
Education             object
Self_Employed         object
ApplicantIncome        int64
CoapplicantIncome    float64
LoanAmount           float64
Loan_Amount_Term     float64
Credit_History       float64
Property_Area         object
Loan_Status           object
dtype: object
```